# Problem in converting .PY scripts to .exe files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

i have got a problem that i have done a small project which can shutdown , restart, hibernate,sleep the pc by buttons using tkinter and OS modules but when trying to convert .py to .exe using pyinstaller it displays the output as completed successfully but when click the executed the executable it says that the Application is non executable.

below I have attached my code .

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from os import system as sys
from tkinter import messagebox as msg

screen = Tk()
screen.title("System - Properties")
screen.geometry("500x500")
screen.resizable(False,False)
screen.configure(background="powderblue")
screen.iconbitmap("LOGO.ico")

canvas1 = Canvas(screen,height=100,width=480,bg="red",bd=5,relief="groove").place(x = 3,y = 0)

Header = Label(canvas1,text="SYSTEM CONTROL",fg="black",bg="tomato",
font=("Courier New",30,"bold")).place(x = 85,y = 30)

canvas2 = Canvas(screen,height=260,width=470,bg="teal",bd=10,relief="sunken").place(x = 3,y = 120)

# button function starts

def shutdown():
    sys("shutdown /s /t 1")

def restart():
    sys("shutdown /r /t 1")

def logoff():
    sys("shutdown /l /t 1")

def hibernate():
    sys("shutdown /h /t 1")

def help():

    content = "This app helps to perform some simple actions \nJust click the button according to your use. \n\n\tDO NOT PLAY WITH THIS"
    msg.showinfo("HELP",content)

def about():
    content= "Author : John Arthur\nDate : 19/07/2021 \nProgramming Language  :  Python"
    msg.showinfo("ABOUT",content)

# button starts

shutdown = Button(canvas2,text="SHUTDOWN",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=shutdown,bg="black",fg="white",
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 40,y=175)

restart = Button(canvas2,text="RESTART",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=restart,bg="black",fg="white",
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 190,y=175)

logoff = Button(canvas2,text="LOG-OFF",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=logoff,bg="black",fg="white",
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 340,y = 175)

hibernate = Button(canvas2,text="HIBERNATE",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=hibernate,bg="black",fg="white",
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 40,y=250)

help = Button(canvas2,text="HELP",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=help,bg="black",fg="white",width=9,
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 190,y=250)

about = Button(canvas2,text="ABOUT",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=about,bg="black",fg="white",
font=("Bell MT",15,"italic")).place(x = 340,y=250)

# function button over


canvas3 = Canvas(screen,height=70,width=480,bg="black",bd=5,relief="groove").place(x=3,y=410)

# control button starts

quit = Button(canvas3,text="exit",bd = 2,relief="sunken",command=exit,bg="orange",fg="black",width=15,
font=("Arial",20,"bold")).place(x = 110,y=425)

# control button ends

screen.mainloop()
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem please .

Comment: What is the command line arguments used for converting the Python script to EXE using PyInstaller?

Comment: There is a very helpful section in the `pyinstaller` documentation called *When things go wrong*. As there is a lot that can go wrong, I suggest you work through it.